# MS Teams App: There was a problem reaching this app

Tags: .net, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

The users on MS Teams desktop reported multiple issues with our MS Teams app.
They see the following error on MS Teams Desktop App:  There was a problem reaching this app. The screen is attached below.
However everything is working (chat, search extension and static app) for these users. Also it is reproduced only in MS Teams **Dektop** client and not in browser client.
The new errors apper in console log when we switch to the Chat tab. The screenshots are attached below.
How can we solve this issue? Why it is reproduced only in Desktop client?
The bot Id is: ef11c144-9b09-4b64-a02f-a36be885f941
[image: MS Teams error]

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CJcu.png)

Comment: Could you please try updating Teams Desktop client and check it again.
Error which you have share does not contains Teams specific errors, it's showing generic error from .js file.

Could you please share more specific error via cleaning these errors and opening bot again.

Comment: Do you have `showLoadingIndicator` set to True in your manifest (it's one of the options if you're using App Studio or similar), or in your final manifest file near the bottom)?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft Here are updated errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CJcu.png . The latest version of MS Teams Desktop is used

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow showLoadingIndicator  is disabled.

Comment: Looks the issue is reproduced not only for our app, but also for other apps with chat.

Comment: The issue is not reproduced for all tenants. I opened MS Teams desktop for another tenant and everything works great. 
I tried to clear cache, restrat PC, update Teams and Windows - nothing helped.

Comment: Looks like there is opened Microsoft incident: 260708099 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69356775/teams-client-update-there-was-a-problem-reaching-this-app

Comment: Hi @vshandra, Yes that is correct. An incident has been already raised for this and concerned team is looking into it.

Comment: @Prithvi-MSFT do you have any updates? When is it expected the isssue will be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is on Microsoft side.
The Microsoft incident ref: **260708099**.
The workarounds now are:

1. Use Teams web app
2. Click 'pop up' button on top right corner of bot chat in MS Teams Desktop

**Update:**
Issue is fixed now. The Teams client restart was required.

Comment: What is bot chat?

Answer (score 1):

After I added .env file under tabs folder it worked. Make sure its under tabs and not been added to another place mistakenly.