# Teams client update - There was a problem reaching this app

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a couple Teams Bots running in our environment currently and since the update to the MS Teams Desktop client to v1.4.00.22976 I've started seeing a *There was a problem reaching this app* error appearing in the Bots via the Desktop client.

[image: Image of MS Teams Client]

Despite the message, the Bots are working fine, but the message still persists. I don't have showLoadingIndicator enabled in the manifest either.

Clicking on *Retry* does nothing nor does signing out and clearing the Teams client cache. However, the Bots appear as they should via the browser, which leads me to believe something has changed on the client side.

I've gone through the logs and cannot see anything relating to the issue. I appreciate this isn't much to go on and can provide the logs on request, but this has only just started happening since the latest client update.

Comment: It seems this is known issue in Teams platform and fix to rollout.

Comment: @SubbaReddiTummuru Did you get this from MSFT Support?  Do you have a case number by any chance?  We are an ISV and we have several dozen customer Tenants facing the same exact issue.

Comment: @Ennova: Here is the MSFT internal incident reference: 260708099

Comment: @SubbaReddiTummuru do you have any updates? When is it expected the isssue will be fixed?

Comment: The fix is expected to begin rolling out on October 4th and reach 100% by October 8th.

Comment: Looks like issue is fixed now. The Teams client restart was required.